# Blazor component implemented under MVC does not get rendered

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, blazor, blazor-server-side

Using .NET Core with the latest release version of server side Blazor, I implemented Blazor components in an existing MVC application (thanks to Chris https://chrissainty.com/using-blazor-components-in-an-existing-mvc-application/) I can only render the Blazor component on the default page (i.e. https://localhost:5433). The Blazor components works totally fine in the default page but when I try to open the view using https://localhost:5433/home/index or any other view, the Blazor component does not get rendered.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [asp.net mvc url routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331439/asp-net-mvc-url-routing)

Comment: That doesn't look related to his question at all...?

Comment: I think [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1) might help you out. You might have to set the routes up specifically for the path.

Comment: This question needs more information and sample code. Set up a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out! To answer some of the questions and a reproducible example:

Create an empty MVC Core Application and follow Chrissianity's tutorial on how to implement Blazor to an existing MVC https://chrissainty.com/using-blazor-components-in-an-existing-mvc-application/

I didn't notice that I was using

```
@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<CoursesList>(**RenderMode.Server**, 
     new { Courses = Model }))
```

rather than

```
@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<CoursesList(**RenderMode.ServerPrerendered**, 
   new { Courses = Model }))
```

When I changed my rendermode, the pages now work.